# Switching from Google Japanese Input directly to Google Keyboard?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, keyboard, gboard, google-japanese-input

I have the following input methods enabled:

- Google Keyboard, English (US)
- Google Japanese Input, Japanese

I use both the Google Keyboard and Google Japanese Input depending on what I'm doing. Going from Google Keyboard to Google Japanese Input is trivial, I simply click the language button and it automatically switches. However I am running into an issue with switching back. Here is a screenshot of the keyboard in use:

[image]

There is a button on the bottom-left that switches between Japanese, numeric, and QWERTY. However the QWERTY is awkward to use and I would prefer to switch it to the Google Keyboard instead. I can accomplish this by holding the button down, but the "Input Options" doesn't list the Google Keyboard as an entry. Instead, I must choose "Select Input Method", then I can choose Google Keyboard.

[image][image][image]

While this is a minor inconvenience, the extra time certainly adds up especially when switching between various contacts in the same application, or when I need to use both Japanese/English when talking to the same person (such as translations, etc...).

Is there a way that I can have it automatically switch to the Google Keyboard when I hold down the button? If not, is there a keyboard that could offer this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is impossible to do in KitKat and previous version. There is no globe (input method switch key) icon, and there is no setting related to it.

However, recent update added this feature, BUT it's only for Android 5.0 Lollipop (as of writing). From "[What's New](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese)",

> (Lollipop) Introduced input method switch key.

On Lollipop, there will be a globe icon on each type of keyboard:

- 12 Keys: On Japanese mode, to the left of 'わ'.
- QWERTY: On Japanese mode, to the left of the spacebar
- Godan keyboard: On Japanese mode, between 'O' and 'W'